# What is the proper approach to defining a dynamic IN clause, based off of parameter flags?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, in-clause

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I've scoured this site and I can't find a straightforward answer to what has to be a common problem.

I have a stored procedure that takes multiple parameters but three of them are flags.  For each flag, flagged as 'Y', I need to insert a value into an `IN` clause.  In other words, consider the following code.

```
CREATE PROC testProc
  @FlagA char(1),
  @FlagB char(1),
  @FlagC char(1)
AS

--... Do stuff...

IF (@FlagA = 'Y')
  --Add 'AVal' to IN list
IF (@FlagB = 'Y')
  --Add 'BVal' to IN list
IF (@FlagC = 'Y')
  --Add 'CVal' to IN list

--... Do more stuff...

SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE testField -- Insert correct IN clause.
```

This is an extremely simplistic version of why my code is trying to accomplish.  I can think of multiple ways of solving this dilemma but none of them feel *correct*.

The best solution that I can come up with is to define a temp table that has one field.  For each flag that is set, I can add a corresponding value into the temp table and then use a `...IN (SELECT * FROM #temp)` statement.

Is this the right approach or is there a more correct solution to this problem?  I'm fine if my solution is the best answer, however, whenever I see simplistic uses of temp tables I'm often suspicious that there is a better approach.

Any clarity would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: That's a cool method. Add values to temp table and then do the IN with a select from temp. Nice! I'm with you, I've come across this several times, dynamic sql (obvious) or a another variable that holds the concatenated value of the flags in proper "IN" form ('Y','N')

Comment: Although you arrive at your list in a different way, the rest of the solution is the same as here (wish I got paid everytime I posted this link as an answer):  http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses.  The tripod link (lol.. tripod, ha!) could be of use for future reference but, generally, I try to avoid two things in SQL wherever possible-- dynamic SQL with EXEC() statements and temp tables.  Yes, each has it's place but as I mentioned, when a problem seems common and simple, I can't believe there isn't a built-in, "correct" solution that doesn't involve either of the two approaches.

Comment: @TabAlleman please stop posting that link as an answer ;-). It is horribly out-dated. Most of the ways it shows to split a CSV list are terribly slow. It does mention a numbers table and the INNER JOIN option, but is otherwise more likely to get someone to use an inefficient approach than a good one. For the record, splitting a CSV list is nearly always done fastest via a CLR function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, please, please do not do Dynamic SQL or multiple OR conditions (each with a specific "flag" parameter). There is a very simple and set-based approach that SQL Server will appreciate:

1. Create a temp table (or table variable)
2. Insert the values for flags coming in with a value of "Y" into it
3. Use that temp table (or table variable) in an `EXISTS` clause

Example:

```sql
DECLARE
  @FlagA CHAR(1),
  @FlagB CHAR(1),
  @FlagC CHAR(1);

SELECT
  @FlagA = 'Y',
  @FlagB = 'n',
  @FlagC = 'y';

DECLARE @Options TABLE (Value VARCHAR(50));

IF (@FlagA = 'Y')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Options (Value) VALUES ('AVal');
END;

IF (@FlagB = 'Y')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Options (Value) VALUES ('BVal');
END;

IF (@FlagC = 'Y')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @Options (Value) VALUES ('CVal');
END;

SELECT *
FROM   MyTable mt
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   @Options op
               WHERE  op.Value = mt.[testField]
              );
```

Of course, it might not hurt to compare performance against your proposed IN list:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable mt
WHERE  mt.[testField] IN (SELECT op.Value FROM @Options op);
```

And, since the value to search for can only appear once, that is technically an INNER JOIN, right? It is not usually my preference to use an `INNER JOIN` purely as a filter, but can't hurt testing :). And this version might work better if [testField] is indexed.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable mt
INNER JOIN @Options op
        ON op.Value = mt.[testField];
```

In either case, using this approach (any one of them) is preferred because it lets SQL Server do what it is tuned to do: work with sets. The `EXISTS` is helpful in that it will stop searching once the first row is found for its query. I suspect that `EXISTS` is better than an `IN` list but with only 3 values it should be tested. However, this approach is also more easily adaptable to adding more "flag" values in the future as that won't change the query.

If you want to do the INNER JOIN option to a table being OUTER JOINed:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   PrimaryTable pt
LEFT JOIN (
             MyTable mt
  INNER JOIN @Options op
          ON op.Value = mt.[testField]
          ) ON mt.ID = pt.ID;
```

Comment: This was the very approach that I was leaning toward (and claimed) in my question. If you can, please elaborate on why this is the best choice.  The more technical, the better. ;) Thank you!

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` statement would work in most cases but I don't think it can for me. My `SELECT` statement is actually pretty complex and the `IN` clause is within an `OUTER JOIN` on top of the parent table.  To my knowledge, if you have a table in an `OUTER JOIN` you can't `INNER JOIN` it to another table without breaking the parent `OUTER JOIN`.  So an Table->ToOuterTable->ToInnerTable won't work.

Comment: @RLH yes, you can INNER JOIN a table to one that is being OUTER JOINed. You just need to group them with parens so that the optimizer knows of the grouping. Or maybe the parens aren't needed based on where the ON clause goes, but at least the parens make it more readable. But I have done this before and it works well.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I'm not sure how but when I've tried, it usually killed my queries.

Comment: I stand corrected (and man is this FAR more efficient!)  Using the join cut the query down from 5-7 seconds, down to 2!  Thank you, thank you!

Comment: @RLH "killed" meaning? performance or expected results? Not sure about performance, but what I updated my answer with (at the bottom) does work. You just need to get the table aliases correct. The `ON` on the outside of the right paren is the OUTER JOIN condition, if not obvious. And if you notice, it is _not_ a subquery.

Comment: @RLH : Great! I am still curious how the INNER JOIN stacks up against the hard-coded IN list (assuming Dynamic SQL), the EXISTS clause, and the other temporary type (i.e. if using a table variable, test with temp table, or other way around).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to check performance on this, but you could use conditional `WHERE` clauses as an alternative. This may not be a great solution, depending on how complicated your actual procedure is, but it gives you something else to consider:

```
DECLARE @FlagA CHAR(1) = 'Y' ,
        @FlagB CHAR(1) = 'N' ,
        @FlagC CHAR(1) = 'Y'

SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   ( @FlagA = 'Y' AND testField = AVal )
     OR ( @FlagB = 'Y' AND testField = BVal )
     OR ( @FlagC = 'Y' AND testField = CVal )
```

With this, the `WHERE` clause on each line will only be evaluated if the first condition is met.

Comment: I had considered some form of conditional statement.  In my case, however, you can replace your `testField IN ...` statements with `tesField = 'valN'`

Comment: @RLH and it will have the same query plan

Comment: @Blam, correct.  I'm not married to the idea of using an `IN` clause, per se, I just have a list of hard-values which I need to check for ONLY IF the flags are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is better but another approach

```
  where @flag1 + testField = 'YAval'
     or @flag2 + testField = 'YBval'
     or @flag2 + testField = 'YCval'
```

or

```
where 'Y' + testField = in ( @flag1 + 'Aval', @flag2 + 'Bval', @flag3 + 'Cval')
```